# RewriteRule not working with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

after doing some research i am still not sure that why this rewrite rule is not working on my server, i have checked on multiple hostings, but to no avail, the problem lies here:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

the last line above does not supply anything to GET on index.php, meaning $_GET is empty. Any suggestions?

PS: trying to implement this -> https://github.com/panique/php-mvc/blob/master/.htaccess

Comment: Can you show the URL you are trying to test with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules look okay. Try a couple of tweaks:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# check existing maps or files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]

# re-writing
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

To get the URL you can use something like this in PHP:

```
$linkArray = explode("/",$_GET['url']);
```

You can stil access your GET parameters. If you use **www.mywebsite.com/home/&message=hello** it will rewrite it to **www.mywebsite.com/?url=home/&message=hello**. So with the explode you can get your URL parameters and for example with $_GET['message'] you can get the message.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment, your suggested changes didnt work. i dont know what could be the underlying problem